# can lambda in vpc "X" access efs in vpc "y"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-efs

can lambda access the data present in efs of different vpc?I tried reading AWS docs but could not find much of details.I know that lambda can access efs in same vpc where it is running.

Comment: I've noticed that you questions with answers, yet not a single answer was ever accepted. Accepting good answers is not only a good practice, but it also reduced duplicates and makes your questions more likely to be answered.

Comment: I will do it from now on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but you have to setup [VPC peering](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-peering.html) between the two VPCs. This way, lambda in one VPC will be able to mount EFS from the other VPC. The only requirement is that both VPCs must be in [same region](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-efs.html).

> The file system and the Lambda function **must be in the same region**. A Lambda function in one account can mount a file system in a different account. For this scenario, you configure **VPC peering** between the function VPC and the file system VPC.